# appletviewer run ok browser not

Tags: file-uri, appletviewer

appletviewer show correctly if within a class in jar file there is the following expression:

```
File objectFile = new File("configurationfile.dat");
```

Running with a browser there is an error. I changed to

```
File objectFile = new File("\\\\mypc:8080/mymavenapp","configurationfile.dat");
```

and success the same. Running with appletviewer DOS windows show the following message:

```
\\mypc:8080\mymavenapp\configurationfile.dat (No se ha encontrado la ruta de acceso de la red)
```

Answer (score 1):

I put the file at the same package of the class and changed the following:

```
objectFile = new File((new URI("file:C:/users/user/documents/NetBeansProjects/mavenHMI2/archivConfHMI.dat")));
                    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(objectFile);
            objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
```

by:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("archivConfHMI.dat"); 
                    objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(is);
```